# ElasticSearch data structure and querying

Tags: elasticsearch

I have next models structure:

```
Product:
  name: char

Shop:
  location: geo_point

ShopProduct:
  shop: ForeignKey(Shop)
  product: ForeignKey(Product)
  price: double
```

I need to implement a search using ElasticSearch (v5.2) by `Product`. So, if user enters some product name, in the results he will receive product name, nearest location and min and max prices. Also, I need to sort by name, location and price.

I have two questions:

**1. Which mapping structure should I use for ElasticSearch indices to implement search by product with sort by locations/prices?**

Currently, I have two indices, first for products and second for shops. The product index has "nested" datatype to shop location. I've added it because I need to implement sort functionality by location and price. I don't feel that it is a good idea, but I'm not sure which data structure I should use to implement sorting. Also, I was thinking about parent-child relationship, but I think it is not a good fit for my data - in the documentation it is mentioned that it should be used for a few parent objects and a lot of children.

```
    # Product Index
    "mappings": {
        "product": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {"type": "string"}
                "locations": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "location": {"type": "geo_point"},
                        "price": {"type": "float"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    # Shop Index
    "mappings": {
        "shop": {
            "properties": {
                "location": {"type": "geo_point"},
                "shop_products": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "product_id": {"type": "long"},
                        "product_name": {"type": "string"},
                        "price": {"type": "float"}
                    }
                },
            }
        }
    }
```

**2. How can I get the nearest location and min/max price for each product?**

I've tried to calculate it using script_fields with script like this, but then noticed that ElasticSearch does not give me access to the nested object. So, this script does not work.

```
    "script_fields": {
        "locations": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "params": {
                    'lat': 50,
                    'lon': -120
                },
                "inline": """
                    def locations = params._source.locations; // I've also try doc['locations.location'].value
                    if (locations.length > 0) {
                        distance = locations[0].location.planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0)
                        for (int i = 1; i < locations.length; ++i) {
                            if (distance > locations[i].location.planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0)) {
                                distance = locations[i].location.planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return distance;
                """
            }
        }
    }
```

Then, I've tried to use aggregation to calculate min/max prices and closest location. The aggregation works for me but ElasticSearch does not have any pagination for the aggs and there is an [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4915).

```
    "aggs": {
    "product": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "name"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "prices": {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "locations"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "price": {
                        "stat": {
                            "field": "locations.price"
                        }
                    },
                    "min_distance": {
                        "min": {
                            "script": {
                                "lang": "painless",
                                "inline":  """
        if (params.lat != 0 && params.lon != 0){
            def distance = doc['locations.location'].planeDistanceWithDefault(params.lat, params.lon, 0);
            if (distance !=0){
                return distance;
            }
        }
    """,
                    "params": {
                        'lat': 50,
                        'lon': -120
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}}}}
```

In my example, each product can have about 30 shops which sell it. So, I don't want to return in the results all available locations, only nearest or which is in delivery area. That is why, I make a separate query to get locations for each product.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for this use case the Product index seems redundant. All you need here is the shop index with a nested query on Product name ( hopefully a keyword field, so an inner term query) then you could use top_hits aggregation with sorting on distance and  size 1(or how many ever closest you  need) to get the nearest shop(s) and stats aggregation to get the min/max price for each shop?

Comment: @sramalingam24 Thank you for the answer. Do you mean that I need to query by shops, not by products, correct? There are some products which are not been sold by any shops at that moment, but I need to show them in the search results. Therefore, I think I need to search by product.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, but your reasoning makes it clear that it wouldn't be a good option for your use case then.

Comment: One workaround is to use a dummy store record with all the products that are not sold in any stores in it, then you can use the method I suggested and filter output on client side